# Oracle Stored Function Defining Cursor Based on Parameter

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, cursor

I want a stored function like so:

```
create function myFunction (someSwitch boolean)
return ...
is
  cursor myCursor (params) is
    [BIG QUERY];
...
```

Where the `BIG QUERY` can have an extra `WHERE` clause if `someSwitch` is true.

Can this be done within the cursor definition and, if so, how? Otherwise, what would be my options: I'm thinking that I could either create two cursors (one with the extra clause, the other without) and then do the logic in the function body. I'm not very satisfied by this approach as the query is very big and I would want to avoid repeating code. Alternatively, I could create the cursor SQL dynamically; but this would incur a performance degradation, right?

Thanks :)

Comment: You'll have to go the dynamic SQL way.

Comment: I thought so :( Never mind: It turns out that my cursor can't access out-of-schema objects, anyway, so it's dead in the water before it starts!... Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the where in this way:

```
where (some_condition or the_other_conditions)
```

AFAIK oracle will do shortcut `OR`. That is: if some_condition is true then the_ohter_condition will not be evaluated(and, anyway, this is not important).

Comment: PL/SQL will use the typical short-circuit evaluation, but in Oracle SQL "Left to right evaluation is not guaranteed for multiple conditions connected using OR" - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#i1034834